# Best method to get data from form and put it to model

Tags: java, algorithm, gwt, user-interface

What is best way to get data from Form (this data input user) and put it to model, if Form have ~20 fields. I don't want to get data like:

```
 textBox1.text = contact.name;
 textBox2.text = contact.lastname;
 textBox3.text = contact.surname; 
  ..............
 textBox20.text = contact.birthday;
```

May be exist some more elegant way ? (for example using cycle)

Comment: I use Java GWT framework(i.e it compiles to JavaScript)

Comment: I don't know this framework but you should add some tags in order to target the good users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at gwt's editor framework: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

I found this to be by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use params hash, i.e.:

```
@contact = Contact.create(params[:contact])
```